# commonHomeTab-min.js:168 Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am getting "map is not defined" in production environment. The same file is working without any issues in local environment. I am exactly not sure what is causing the issue.

```
$("#mobility-home-search-text").val(map[[$("#d2LSearchType").val()]]).css("color","#CCCCCC");
```

I believe the function "map" is not available in the workspace. Can someone throw some light on this issue as it sounds weird.

Comment: Brackets are off, making `map` to refer to an object instead of a function. Also it might need the context, i.e. a `jQueryObject.map(...)`.

Comment: What is 'map' in this context? Is it a function you wrote somewhere? Is that definition in this file? What's different about your local and production environments?